# Parsing text with regex in Python: determine match order and mapping value to object type?

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to use an 'estate description' field to obtain information regarding different houses as an exercise for learning python. What I'm interested in (what a lot of sites do *not* show) is how many rooms there are and, more importantly, how big each room/area is. I have the total number of rooms per property (which was scraped separately), with which I'll be able to guide to approximate how many rooms I'll allow per description.

The following examples are strings that occur and that I want to dissect. The following strings are snippets that occur in sentences, as exemplified in the first example.

```
This wonderful apartment has a size of 250m2...which consists of a \                  
Light living room (ca. 5,81 x 5,75 m)... the view from building is xxx and leads into the          
...Lovely kitchen with a lovely fridge (300x575)...  
three bedrooms (5m2, 12m2 and 15m2)            
two bedrooms (3,55 x 3,40 and 3,54 x 2,27 m)   
a nice balcony (15, 15m2)                      
beautiful outdoor space (20m2)
```

The issue is as follows: getting most room sizes is not that difficult utilizing the following regex:

```
(\d{1,4}.{0,2}m[ .]?[2|xb2])|            # Finds 16m2
( \d{1,4}[.,]?\d{0,3}                    # Finds 3.90 x 3,00 m
  [ ]?[x]?[ ]\d{1,4}[.,]?\d{0,3}[ ?]m)|  #
(\d{1,4}[ ]?x[ ]?\d{1,4})                # Finds 640x390
```

The issue I'm having is that twofold:

How do I match them in order? i.e.: first find option A, then find option B? Observing the current behavior think regex prefers shorter strings over longer strings, and is not matching them from left to right. I could maybe do a regex, replace with nothing and then move on in a loop?

Second: I have a hard time trying to envision how I'd be able to go from a list of matches with these room/area sizes to mapping them to the kind of area they describe (if possible). For example: 250m2 found => Look for a list of 'area types' (["bedroom", "kitchen", "apartment") in the previous ~ 20 characters or so in the past x words (going backwards), or perhaps via another regex looking back?

I'm not expecting a 100% solution, I'm just trying to grasp how I'd go about parsing such text and trying to obtain interesting info from blobs of text. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at re.finditer?  It allows you to map over matches.  You can wrap it in "list()" to get left to right matches.  For the second part, you might want to look at (?P<name>...) syntax, which allows you to associate the match to the kind of string, which you can then map to a parser.

Comment: I want the 15m2 bedroom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part of your question:  If you intend to match them in order, you could strictly sequence  the regexes into something like a list.

```
regexes = [re.compile(r'expression 1'), re.compile(r'expression 2'), ...]
for regex in regexes:
  match = regex.search(input_text)
  if match: break

if not match:
  print("We didn't find anything!")
```

Second part of your question:  If you anticipate those blobs coming in similar structure to the samples you've posted, perhaps isolate the portion of the input string up to the point where a digit first appears and analyze just that portion.

```
fuzzy_regex = re.compile(r'^(\D*)(.*)$')
(before_numbers, part_with_numbers) = fuzzy_regex.search(input_string).groups()
# Analyze before_numbers to see what kind of room, etc.
# Analyze part_with_numbers to see square footage, etc.
```

A more concrete example:

```
>>> import re
>>> def dissect(text):
...   return re.search(r'^(\D*)(.*)$', text).groups()
... 
>>> dissect('The entire apartment is 250m2')
('The entire apartment is ', '250m2')
>>> dissect('three bedrooms (5m2, 12m2 and 15m2)')
('three bedrooms (', '5m2, 12m2 and 15m2)')
```

Comment: The first part is perfect & exactly what I needed, thanks! On the second part, I'll edit the question a bit and elaborate: but these strings actually appear in sentences and, as such, I'm currently not aware as to how I would extract these snippets from it? Something like: for each match, extract the previous 5 words or so? Split the text contents (~4 paragraphs, multiple sentences per paragraph) into sentences before doing this?

Comment: Splitting the input into sentences seems like a pretty good plan if you are confident that most of the time your data will be well-behaved - in particular, that the metrics for a given room will occur in the same sentence.  You could then consider each sentence a unit of work and analyze it in the way that we discussed.